# I get value from response and show it to front end but when i refresh the page it goes blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so when i fetch

```
"desiredBranch": "Abdul Hakeem Br.-0231",
"selectedCity": "Abdul Hakeem",
```

these two fields from the response the value comes in the response but when i refresh the page it goes blank

```
applicants[0]["selectedCity"] =
      account &&
      account.get("selectedCity") === null
        ? ""
        : {
            value:
              account &&
              account.get("selectedCity"),
          };
applicants[0]["desiredBranch"] =
      accountDetailApplicationLevel &&
      accountDetailApplicationLevel.get("desiredBranch") === null
        ? ""
        : {
            value:
              accountDetailApplicationLevel &&
              accountDetailApplicationLevel.get("desiredBranch"),
          };
```

this is how i am getting the response from the back end in the useEffect and it is correct because it shows these values sometimes on page refresh but sometimes it go away

```
<MaterialAutoCompleteTypeable
          placeholder="Select from the list"
          topAdornment="Desired City for branch"
          disabled={disableAllFields}
          selectedItem={props.selectedCity}
          error={!props.validationResult.isValidDesiredBranch}
          onSelect={(data, dataObject) =>
            props.handleChange("selectedCity", dataObject)
          }
          data={cities}
        />

        <MaterialAutoCompleteTypeable
          placeholder="Select from the list"
          disabled={disableAllFields}
          topAdornment="Desired branch"
          selectedItem={props.desiredBranch}
          error={!props.validationResult.isValidDesiredBranch}
          onSelect={(data, dataObject) =>
            props.handleChange("desiredBranch", dataObject)
          }
          data={disredBranchs && disredBranchs.toJS()}
          isMandatory
        />
```

this is the field on selectedItem prop my state is coming which user select it
but it keep going empty when i refresh the paage sometimes and sometimes it appears

what is the problem ?